# Final permissions on OS X Bower and NPM

Tags: macos, permissions, npm, bower, osx-elcapitan

hope you having a good day.

I am a Web Frontend designer and i'm tired about MAC OSX El Capitan and his sick permissions systems on files and folders, the next is happening:

Every time that i tried to get any Bower package, NPM, or whatever console package i get this problem:

Example: 'Bower install angular-translate'

Console response:

***'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/carl/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.'***

This is not just for this package in specific, it happend with everything that i tried to download/install in every place in my laptop.

I am the administrator on this machine, i been google that like 5 or 10 times always getting same results and always going to the same way (solutions like 'chmod-R 777* on the folder/file').

My question is the next:

There is some 'permanent' way to get all my files and folders 'global' administrator permissions no matter what? i mean, i know that is not secure, pero it is ok, i am the only one who use this laptop.

Thank you so much for your help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the issue. I ran the command 'sudo chown -R $USER ~/' from the terminal. While inside the same terminal window, I then ran 'bower install' which solved my issue! Afterwards, I was able to install other packages(Ex. bower install bootstrap --save.